# Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

*InvalidOperationException: Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection since either parent or the subquery doesn't project necessary information required to uniquely identify it and correctly generate results on the client side. This can happen when trying to correlate on keyless entity type. This can also happen for some cases of projection before 'Distinct' or some shapes of grouping key in case of 'GroupBy'. These should either contain all key properties of the entity that the operation is applied on, or only contain simple property access expressions.*

This error is driving me crazy.

Reading [link 1](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23830) and [link 2](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29718) I get the reason for the error (entity lacks key to ensure uniqueness), but still I'm not able to fix it.

I've tried adding a key/Id to both `CompanyDto` and `ExpenseItem` from their parents but still no luck.

```
public class Company
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public IList<ExternalCourse> ExternalCourses { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyDto
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public IList<ExpenseItem> ExpenseItems { get; set; }
}

public class ExpenseItem
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set; }
    public string Title {get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string Title {get; set; }
    public DateTime? CancelDate {get; set; }
    public DateTime? ApprovalDate {get; set; }
    public double AttendPrice { get; set; }

    public IList<CourseExpense> CourseExpenses { get; set; }
}

public class CourseExpense
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }

    public string Title {get; set; }
    public DateTime Date {get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalCourse
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string Title {get; set; }
    public DateTime Date {get; set; }
    public double TotalExpenseAmount { get; set; }
}
```

For each company in my database I need a list of data (`ExpenseItem`) which I retrieve with `Select`s and `Union`s like this:

```
        var companies = await _dbContext.Companies
            .Select(x => new CompanyDto {
                Company = x,
                Expenses = x.Courses.Where(y => y.CancelDate == null && y.ApprovalDate != null).SelectMany(y => y.CourseExpenses).Select(y => new ExpenseItem { Date = y.Date, Title = y.Title, Amount = y.Amount })
                                            .Union(x.Courses.Where(y => y.CancelDate == null && y.ApprovalDate != null).Select(y => new ExpenseItem { Date = y.ApprovalDate.Value, Title = y.Title, Amount = y.AttendPrice }))
                                            .Union(x.ExternalCourses.Select(y => new ExpenseItem { Date = y.Date, Title = y.Title, Amount = y.TotalExpenseAmount }))
                                            .ToList()
            })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Company.Name)
        .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

If I omit the last Union, the query executes without any errors.

I also tried another approach inspired by the second link, but the error's the same:

```
        var companies = await _dbContext.Companies
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Company = x,
            Exp1 = x.Courses.Where(y => y.CancelDate == null && y.ApprovalDate != null && y.CompanyId == x.Id).SelectMany(y => y.CourseExpenses).Select(y => new ExpenseItem { Date = y.Date, Title = y.Title, Amount = y.Amount }),
            Exp2 = x.Courses.Where(y => y.CancelDate == null && y.ApprovalDate != null && y.CompanyId == x.Id).Select(y => new ExpenseItem { Date = y.ApprovalDate.Value, Title = y.Title, Amount = y.AttendPrice }),
            Exp3 = x.ExternalCourses.Where(y => y.CompanyId == x.Id).Select(y => new ExpenseItem { Date = y.Date, Title = y.Title, Amount = y.TotalExpenseAmount })
        })
        .Select(x => new CompanyList
        {
            Company = x.Company,
            ExpenseItems = x.Exp1.Union(x.Exp2).Union(x.Exp3).ToList()
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Company.Name).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution (or at least one of them) was to execute the query with the anonymous select and afterwards project it into the DTO like this:

```
var companies = (await _dbContext.Companies
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Company = x,
            Exp1 = x.Courses.Where(y => y.CancelDate == null && y.ApprovalDate != null && y.CompanyId == x.Id).SelectMany(y => y.CourseExpenses).Select(y => new ExpenseItem { Date = y.Date, Title = y.Title, Amount = y.Amount }),
            Exp2 = x.Courses.Where(y => y.CancelDate == null && y.ApprovalDate != null && y.CompanyId == x.Id).Select(y => new ExpenseItem { Date = y.ApprovalDate.Value, Title = y.Title, Amount = y.AttendPrice }),
            Exp3 = x.ExternalCourses.Where(y => y.CompanyId == x.Id).Select(y => new ExpenseItem { Date = y.Date, Title = y.Title, Amount = y.TotalExpenseAmount })
        }).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync())
        .Select(x => new CompanyList
        {
            Company = x.Company,
            ExpenseItems = x.Exp1.Union(x.Exp2).Union(x.Exp3).ToList()
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Company.Name).ToList();
```